# Complex contour integral: How does the stationary point method used in this case?

Tags: complex-analysis, laplace-transform, contour-integration, complex-integration

I was reading a paper which has the following integral in order to do the inverse Laplace transformation:

$$
I=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{-i\infty+\gamma}^{i\infty+\gamma} e^{st}\frac{\Omega^2}{(s^2+4\Omega^2)\sqrt{s^2+4\Delta^2}\sinh^{-1}\frac{s}{2\Delta}}\mathrm{d}s 
$$

To do this integral, we draw the following contour, in which we can see three poles and two branch points:
[image]

The branch cut is defined as $$\mathcal{B}_{\pm}(\delta)=\{\pm 2i\Delta\pm ir e^{\pm i\delta}|r\in [0,+\infty)\}$$.

My question is, **how can I do the blue and red path in large $t$ limit**, here is what the paper says:

> The asymptotic behavior of the integrals C± for t → ∞ is evaluated by
>   the saddle-point method. Finally we end up with long-time asymptotic
>   forms of the (integral)

I have been working on this integral for two days and learn the very basic knowledge about the stationary point method(the steepest descent method), but still I cannot figure this out.

Please help me with it, thanks in advance.

The answer is as follows, the part with blue lines is the integral along branch cut which I am asking for help.

[image]

Comment: That's an odd way to attack the problem, but maybe I have just been in a bubble all these years.  My approach would go directly down the imaginary axis, with a small semicircular detour around the pole on each side of the branch line.

Comment: @RonGordon I tried follow your suggestion, i.e. an "deformed keyhole" contour. I evaluated the deformed part(a small semicircular detour around the pole), it is zero. However, I still cannot solve the problem. Especially how this is related with the stationary method.